# Windows Forms C#: Access TabControl from UserControl

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have a TabControl and a UserControl interacting in the following way:
Each time a new tab is opened, the UserControl loads onto the new tab.

In the UserControl there's a Panel, a TexBox and a Button. Each time text is entered into the TexBox and the Button is pressed, it's supposed to update the title *of the current tab*

How do I access the tab title from within the UserControl?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: Event, or travel up with parent of type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better if the user control does not know where it is embedded into.

Consider providing a `TitleChanged` event in the user control instead. Then it can be the responsibility of the consumer to update itself accordingly.

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    // [...]

    public string Title { get; private set; }
    public event EventHandler TitleChanged;

    // [...]

    private void MyTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Title = MyTextBox.Text;
        TitleChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

And the necessary code of the consumer class can be sg like this:

```
// after subscribing the myUserControl.TitleChanged event:
private void MyUserControl_TitleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myTab.Text = myUserControl.Title;
}
```

Even better if you use data binding in the user form:

```
myTab.DataBindings.Add(nameof(TabPage.Text), myUserControl, nameof(MyUserControl.Title));
```